# Is it possible to use hfs+ for nfs exporting on linux?

Tags: linux, nfs, hfs+

I have an esata external driver which is of hfs+ format. I have already disabled the journaling function and managed to mount it with both read&write supports in my ubuntu system. 
However, when I tried to set it up for nfs exports, it told me something like:

```
exportfs: /path/to/mounted/folder does not support NFS export
```

I suspect nfs export doesn't support hfs+? is there a solution for not formatting the hdd into ext4? the main reason is because I have too much data on it, and I also like to use it to exchange files with my osx system sometimes.

Comment: It seems like I have to compile the hfsplus module into kernel.

Comment: Have tried compling hfsplus into kernel... no luck, it doesn't work either..